# Regular expression for search and replace in dreamweaver

Tags: html, regex, dreamweaver

I would like to write a regular expression to do some replacing in Dreamweaver. I need a regular expression for the `<abbr>` tag in html.

For example, in my page the following text will appear:

```
Photo: NASA
```

I would like it to become:

```
Photo: <abbr title="National Aeronautics and Space Administration">NASA</abbr>
```

Note that some instances of the word "NASA" in my HTML is already surrounded by `<abbr>` tags. If that is the case, don't put additional `<abbr>` tags around it.

Comment: Give us an example to show sample text and desired output.

Comment: @vaman There is this text in my page: 
Photo: NASA
I want to remplace it by:
    <abbr title="National Aeronautics and Space Administration">NASA</abbr>

but if the word NASA is already between ABBR tags, dont put additionnal tags

Comment: When you say regex & Dreamweaver, are you talking about a find/replace function in Dreamweaver that uses regex finding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've left out lookbehinds. I'm not sure what type of regex Dreamweaver supports.

Try using the following regular expression:

```
NASA(?!( *</abbr>)|(\.\w+)|("))
```

It will not match any instance of NASA that is:

- followed by `</abbr>` regardless of whitespace between NASA and `</abbr>`
- followed by a `.` and other characters, e.g. nasa.gov is considered invalid.
- followed by a `/`, e.g. test.gov/nasa/ is considered invalid.
- followed by a `"` it's invalid.
- The regexp will match NASA when it's in a quote like this:

  ```
  "This NASA is surrounded by quotes"
  ```
- but won't when it's the only thing in quotes:

  ```
  "NASA"
  ```
- . . . you can see the trend here, tack on additional "or" statements where necessary.

I tested it with the following string:

> This sentence ends with NASA. This Regex will work with NASA, but not
>   with URLs such as nasa.gov/test/nasa/page.html. It won't work with
>   <abbr>NASA</abbr> as it's surrounded by <abbr>
>   tags. "This NASA is surrounded by quotes", but will be
>   matched as it's not formatted like this "NASA" is.

Then you can simply do a find using that regex, and replace with:

```
<abbr title="National Aeronautics and Space Administration">NASA</abbr>
```

---

Note: The quotes are a limitation that I can't get around, or I don't know how to get around easily. I suggest that if you have to do this for a lot of documents that you use some type of scripting language (Python for example) and avoid one large regexp and break it down into logical statements, but that is another question entirely.

Best of luck!

Comment: Try [@nickb's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11619098/586621), if that doesn't work for you there may be a checkbox in the find/replace you have to toggle to use regular expressions in Dreamweaver. edit: look [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt1.html) for more information on this.

Comment: I uncheck the "match case" and your regex is working, but i have the word "nasa" in some url, wich I don't want to replace

Comment: As in http://www.somewebsite/nasa/something.html and it's matching "nasa" in that url?

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if that works better for you.

Comment: it's working but I have the following sentence "... NASA, ..." wich is not working because of the "," or the "."

Comment: Updated again. I'd move this to chat if I could but it says you don't have enough reputation.

Comment: i'ts working great, just a last request: I have some NASA word in my title or alt attribute, is it possible to not match NASA when it's surronded by " ?

Comment: works great :) not every regex is perfect but it fit my usual needs :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Search for: `NASA`

Replace with:

```
<abbr title="National Aeronautics and Space Administration">NASA</abbr>
```

Then search for:

```
<abbr title="National Aeronautics and Space Administration"><abbr title="National Aeronautics and Space Administration">NASA</abbr></abbr>
```

Replace with:

```
<abbr title="National Aeronautics and Space Administration">NASA</abbr>
```

Tada! =)

Answer (score 0):

If lookbehinds are supported, this is fairly simple.

Search:

```
(?<!>)NASA
```

Replace:

```
<abbr title="National Aeronautics and Space Administration">NASA</abbr>
```

This finds `NASA` entries that are not prefixed with an `>`. So, `NASA` will match, `>NASA` will not.